Extract tweets containing a keyword from a particular user account ERROR
I'm trying to extract tweets containing a keyword from a particular user. However, I encountered the following error message.
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.
Currently, I'm using a free access level. Is this problem only caused by the restriction on the access level. Below is the code I implemented.
import tweepy
def get_twitter(user, keyword):
    query = f'from:{user} "{keyword}"'
    tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at'], max_results=100)
    filtered_tweets = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets.data] if tweets.data else []
    return filtered_tweets

bearer_token = 'XXX'


client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

user = 'XXX'
keyword = 'XXX'
tweets = get_twitter(user, keyword)
print(tweets)

I also used another version of code but the same error message was returned.
import tweepy
def get_twitter(user, keyword):
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=user, tweet_mode='extended')
    filtered_tweets = []

    for tweet in tweets:
        for keyword in keyword:
            if keyword.lower() in tweet.full_text.lower():
                filtered_tweets.append(tweet.full_text)
                break

    return filtered_tweets

consumer_key = 'XXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXX'
access_token = 'XXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = 'XXX'
keyword = 'XXX'
tweets = get_twitter(user, keyword)
print(tweets)

Is that possible to extract tweets containing a keyword from a particular user account without upgrading the access level from free to basic?

"Is that possible to extract tweets containing a keyword from a particular user account without upgrading the access level from free to basic?" No, and this should be clear from X's documentation.
